# Logstash Duplicate Events

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I have two configuration files for Logstash: `test1.conf` and `test2.conf`.
Each one of them has it's own flow of `input -> filter -> ouput`.

Both of them have the same filter and `elasticsearch` output writing to the same index.

My problem is that Logstash is writing duplicate events to the ElasticSearch index, no matter which input I choose to test (every event becomes two identical events instead of one).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Logstash has one pipeline named `main` which automatically detects all *.conf* files in *conf.d* folder; this configuration is set at [pipelines.yml](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/7.6/pkg/pipelines.yml) file:

```
- pipeline.id: main
  path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/*.conf"
```

If you have multiple *.conf* files under one pipeline, Logstash will merge them together, causing all filters and outputs to be performed on all of the inputs, so in this case, no matter which input is receiving events, it will go through two paths of filter/output, causing duplicate writing to ElasticSearch (identical events if the filters/outputs are the same for both *.conf* files).

---

### Solutions

**1. Move filter/output into a separate file**

If your filters/outputs are the same across the config files, move filter/output into a separate file.  So now you have two *.conf* files, one for each input, and a third *.conf* file for the filter/output. With this setup every input will go through only one processing path.

For example:

**`input1.conf`**

```
input {
  # input 1
}
```

**`input2.conf`**

```
input {
  # input 2
}
```

**`filter_output.conf`**

```
filter {
  # common filter
}  

output {
  # common output
}
```

You can check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43784553/7804876) for another example when this solution should be chosen.

Note that If the filters/output are the same but you still want to refer them as complete different processing paths, please keep reading.

---

**2. Split the *.conf* files to different pipelines**

If you need every *.conf* file to be independent, split the *.conf* files to different pipelines.

In order to do that, just edit `pipelines.yml` file.
For example:

**`pipelines.yml`**

```
- pipeline.id: test1
path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/test1.conf"

- pipeline.id: test2
path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/test2.conf"
```

Read more about [Multiple Pipelines](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/multiple-pipelines.html)

---

**3. Separate by types**
Tag each input with different type and check it later on the filters/outputs with if statement.

You can read more about it in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20562031/7804876).

Comment: Have you just published an already answered question and your solution at the same time? Out of curiosity: why not a blog post, then?

Comment: Hey @glenacota :) "it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged": https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/